# Image upload issue in wordpress 3.5.1

Tags: image, wordpress, upload

There is a issue in wordpress for uploading image at the time of creating an article.

Steps to regenerate the issue.

Posts -> Add new posts -> Add Media -> Upload files.

Select a Image to upload, Upload process will start.

it gives an error "An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later."

Then go it Media ->Library

The image is uploaded in the Library, sometimes image is being uploaded multiple time.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set permissions 777 on upload folder ? if you set 777 already and problem is still there then this is about your theme problem you should contact to your theme provider..